# how to create a macro that enter a data then lock the entered data

Tags: excel, vba

Using a command button, how can I make my command button lock its associated cell?

Here's my code.

```
Private Sub TimeGo_Click()
With Me.TimeGo
If .Caption = "Start Time" Then
        Rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(Rw, 1).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
        .Caption = "End Time"


    Else: .Caption = "Start Time"
        Cells(Rw, 2).Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
        Cells(Rw, 3).Formula = "=mod(RC[-1]-RC[-2],1)"      

    End If
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C200")) Is Nothing Then 'set your range here
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="mypassword"
  Target.Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="mypassword"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is `TimeGo` the command button you want to use to lock the cell? If so, which cell would you like to lock?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but if I understand correctly, then you want the TimeGo_Click to call the Worksheet_Change subs to both lock the cell.

If so, I'd recommend a new sub that contains the code that can be called from both the Worksheet_Change and TimeGo_Click.  You would then call it from both subs as illusatrated (I did not include TimeGo_Click sub for brevity, and I'm not sure where in the sub you would want the call to go):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Call LockSingeCell(Target)

End Sub



 Private Sub LockSingeCell(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C200")) Is Nothing Then 'set your range here
     ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="mypassword"
     Target.Locked = True
     ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="mypassword"
   End If

End Sub
```